# Area Under Disease Progress Curve (AUDPC)

Tags: r, dataframe, function

I am trying to apply the function "audpc" from the package "agricolae" to my data base to calculate the area under disease progress curve (audpc). Information about the function and the package:

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/agricolae/versions/1.3-5/topics/audpc

I understand how the function works, but my problem relates how this function should be applied to my data. I have a data frame with different field trials (ID). For each ID, there are disease assessments for diferent diseases. These assessments were made at different time points in order to assess the disease intensity (proportion of plants that were diseased out of the total number of plants in that given field trial). My data base looks like this:

| ID | Week | rust | mildew | scald |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 35 | 1 | 20 | 32 |
| 1 | 36 | 5 | 29 | 39 |
| 1 | 37 | 12 | 45 | 58 |
| 1 | 38 | 23 | 80 | 96 |
| 2 | 17 | 0 | 2 | 5 |
| 2 | 18 | 0 | 4 | 9 |
| 2 | 19 | 2 | 8 | 15 |
| 2 | 20 | 6 | 15 | 30 |
| 2 | 21 | 13 | 30 | 69 |

Each ID (field trial) has different number of entries (different number of weeks where the disease assessment were made) and obviously different values of disease intensity for each disease. What I would like to obtain is the audpc value for each ID and disease (rust, mildew, scald). Is it possible to do it using the audpc funtion in the package agricolae, or a user-defined function has to be created?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the dplyr package, you can `group_by` ID, and apply the `audpc` function `across` each disease column:

```r
library(agricolae)
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(across(rust:scald, ~ audpc(.x, Week)))
#> # A tibble: 2 x 4
#>      ID  rust mildew scald
#>   <int> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1  29      124   161
#> 2     2  14.5     43    91
```

---

**Data from question in reproducible format**

```r
df <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), Week = c(35L, 
36L, 37L, 38L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L), rust = c(1L, 5L, 12L, 
23L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 6L, 13L), mildew = c(20L, 29L, 45L, 80L, 2L, 
4L, 8L, 15L, 30L), scald = c(32L, 39L, 58L, 96L, 5L, 9L, 15L, 
30L, 69L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))

df
#>   ID Week rust mildew scald
#> 1  1   35    1     20    32
#> 2  1   36    5     29    39
#> 3  1   37   12     45    58
#> 4  1   38   23     80    96
#> 5  2   17    0      2     5
#> 6  2   18    0      4     9
#> 7  2   19    2      8    15
#> 8  2   20    6     15    30
#> 9  2   21   13     30    69
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Many thanks! it worked, but for some reason the audpc values that I obtain are all negative, but the absolute values are correct. Strange... I will try to find out why this is happening. Thank you again

Comment: Okey, I found out why the negative values. In my database, values for the week variable were in descending order. I used the following code 

df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(across(rust:scald, ~ audpc(.x, sort(Week))))
And it worked. 
Thanks again Allan!